# Data from Excel File and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I have this huge master excel file, and I am unpacking a few variables, and my code is expectedly not working that well.  I am using Spyder for Python, and it says that there is an ordered dictionary for a few variables, and as I go to unpack the variables to plot the data its not working. Thanks in advance for your help. The Lactose are the sheet names and I am getting the data in those columns and plotting them a simple operation I thought...but it wasn't. My issue is that I am trying to use for loops to collect data from a master excel file, then use another for loop to grab that data and plot it.  The task is to the following it should run like this read Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, and so on columns A,B, M,N (not exact columns or sheetnames and then plot that data and produce pairs of graphs. The problem that is actually occurring is that it won't assign title or produce a total of 16 graphs paired into 8 sections.

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
from scipy import constants
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


d = ['Lactose.450g.2p', 'Lactose.229g.16p', 'Lactose.343g.16p', 
 'Lactose.375g.2p','Lactose.400g.16p', 'Lactose.419g.16p', 
 'Lactose.425g.2p', 'Lactose.500g.2p']
for i in d:
       reference = []
       list_reference  = pd.read_excel('C:\\Kean\\MasterFileLactose071019.xlsx', sheet_name = [i])
       reference.append(list_reference)
       xaxis_samp = pd.read_excel('C:\\Kean\\MasterFileLactose071019.xlsx', sheet_name = [i], usecols = 'C' , skiprows = [0,1])
       yaxis_samp = pd.read_excel('C:\\Kean\\MasterFileLactose071019.xlsx', sheet_name = [i], usecols = 'D' , skiprows = [0,1])
       xaxis_ref = pd.read_excel('C:\\Kean\\MasterFileLactose071019.xlsx', sheet_name = [i], usecols = 'I', skiprows = [0,1])
       yaxis_ref = pd.read_excel('C:\\Kean\\MasterFileLactose071019.xlsx', sheet_name = [i], usecols ='J', skiprows = [0,1])
       for e1, e2, e3, e4, e5 in zip(xaxis_samp,yaxis_samp,xaxis_ref,yaxis_ref, [i]):
           fig_ref, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 1, figsize = (10,10))
           ax1.plot(e3, e4)
           ax1.set_title( 'Reference Spectrum Teflon Tablet')
           ax1.grid(True)
           ax1.set_xlim(0,3)
           ax1.set(xlabel = 'TeraHertz (THz)', ylabel = 'Electric field (a.u.)')
           ax2.plot(e1,e2)
           ax2.set_title('Sample Spectrum ' + str(e5) + ' Tablet')
           ax2.grid(True)
           ax2.set_xlim(0,3)
           ax2.set(xlabel = 'TeraHertz (THz)', ylabel = 'Electric field (a.u.)')
```

Comment: What is your issue? Also, please fix your indentation.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Using a for loop to collect data, then use another for loop to grab that data and plot it?

Comment: That's not an answer to their question @EnlightenedFunky. What do you *expect* to happen, and what is *actually* happening?

Comment: @Calvin Godfrey Ok I expect it to read Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, and so on columns A:C (not exact columns or sheetnames and then plot that data.

Comment: And what is actually happening?

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey The problem that is actually occurring is that it won't assign title and not producing a total of 16 graphs paired into 8 sections.

Comment: Hey guys got an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
from scipy import constants
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


d = ['Lactose.450g.2p', 'Lactose.229g.16p', 'Lactose.343g.16p', 
     'Lactose.375g.2p','Lactose.400g.16p', 'Lactose.419g.16p', 
     'Lactose.425g.2p', 'Lactose.500g.2p']
for i in d:
     reference = []
     list_reference  = pd.read_excel('C:\\Kean\\MasterFileLactose071019.xlsx', sheet_name = [i])
     reference.append(list_reference)
     xaxis_samp = pd.read_excel('C:\\Kean\\MasterFileLactose071019.xlsx', sheet_name = [i], usecols = 'C' , skiprows = [0,1])
     yaxis_samp = pd.read_excel('C:\\Kean\\MasterFileLactose071019.xlsx', sheet_name = [i], usecols = 'D' , skiprows = [0,1])
     xaxis_ref = pd.read_excel('C:\\Kean\\MasterFileLactose071019.xlsx', sheet_name = [i], usecols = 'I', skiprows = [0,1])
     yaxis_ref = pd.read_excel('C:\\Kean\\MasterFileLactose071019.xlsx', sheet_name = [i], usecols ='J', skiprows = [0,1])
     for e1, e2, e3, e4, e5 in zip(xaxis_samp,yaxis_samp,xaxis_ref,yaxis_ref,d):
     fig_ref, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 1, figsize = (10,10))
           ax1.plot(xaxis_ref[e3], yaxis_ref[e4])
           ax1.set_title( 'Reference Spectrum Teflon Tablet')
           ax1.grid(True)
           ax1.set_xlim(0,3)
           ax1.set(xlabel = 'TeraHertz (THz)', ylabel = 'Electric field (a.u.)')
           ax2.plot(xaxis_samp[e1],yaxis_samp[e2])
           ax2.set_title('Sample Spectrum Tablet of '+ i)
           ax2.grid(True)
           ax2.set_xlim(0,3)
           ax2.set(xlabel = 'TeraHertz (THz)', ylabel = 'Electric field (a.u.)')
```

Comment: This answer produces the 16 graphs, and it produces the string title on top of the graphs working really well.  If anyone would like to better the code of make it simpler be my guest.